# How to write an idempotent file update in a Bash script?

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script that will update a configuration file. Right now it simply moves the file into place:

```
if [ ! -e /path/to/file.conf ]; then
  mv file.conf /path/to/file.conf
fi
```

However, now I realize that I may want to make changes to that file in the future, so a simple move won't work if the file is already there. How do I write this so that the file is updated with the right contents in a way that allows me to execute the same script multiple times (idempotent)?

Comment: What's the criteria to determine whether the file should be updated or not?

Comment: What do you mean a simple move won't work? If you remove that `if` condition, the `mv` command will happily overwrite the destination file.

Comment: Won't it give an error saying a file already exists in that location?

Comment: Not unless you use the `-i` flag, like: `mv -i file.conf /path/to/file.conf`. The `-i` flag is nice to use for safety, without it `mv` simply overwrites the destination

Comment: I'm not sure what the criteria is. Just that it has the same contents as the one that is supposed to be there.

Comment: You mean new file replace exists one? What mean update right content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
if cmp -s file.conf /path/to/file.conf
then : OK - identical
else mv /path/to/file.conf /path/to/file.conf.$(date +%Y%m%d.%H%M%S)
     mv file.conf /path/to/file.conf
fi
```

That preserves a dated copy of the previous version of the configuration file, which makes it easier to rollback if something goes wrong.  There are other, arguably better, ways to handle that.  The trouble is that it dates the configuration file with when it was replaced, not when it was created.

So, an alternative is:

```
if cmp -s file.conf /path/to/file.conf
then : OK - identical
else now=$(date +%Y%m%d.%H%M%S)
     mv file.conf /path/to/file.conf.$now
     rm /path/to/file.conf
     ln -s /path/to/file.conf.$now /path/to/file.conf
fi
```

This leaves you with a symlink called `/path/to/file.conf` that points to a dated version of the configuration file — at the time it was created.  You can remove the symlink and put in a different version at any time, or change it to point to an older version without necessarily removing the newer version, etc.

Comment: Nice. I like that idea.